# Make overlay only over image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my black overlay with text only to be over my image itself (and not over, well, everything else also as is now). Is it possible what I aim to do? When the black overlay shows it also covers my product-title and that is wrong.

```css
.image-video-linkmas img {    
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 236px;
 margin: 0;
 position:relative;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0px;
}

.product-details:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}

.product-details .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    /*vertical-align: middle;*/
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
    /*padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="well sb">
        <div>
            <div class="product-details">
                <div class="image-video-linkmas">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="#" src=
                    "http://lorempixel.com/300/300"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="overlay">
                <div class="intro-descriptioncar">
                    intro-car
                </div>
                <div class="userfield1car">
                    car1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-title">
            product-title
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your markup and wrap your `.overlay` element inside the `.image-video-linkmas` one.

---

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/oxexh2go/)**

---

```css
.image-video-linkmas {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.image-video-linkmas img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 236px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px;
}
.image-video-linkmas:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
.image-video-linkmas .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  /*vertical-align: middle;*/
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  /*padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="well sb">
  <div>
    <div class="product-details">
      <div class="image-video-linkmas">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          <img alt="#" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300">
        </a>
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="intro-descriptioncar">
            intro-car
          </div>
          <div class="userfield1car">
            car1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      product-title
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.product-details .overlay {
        position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 7px;
    width: 14.8%;
    height: 29%;
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
}
```